# Execute MongoDB script on Spring Boot start

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I need to initialize a `Mongo DB` with some script file like Spring do with `JPA` and `import.sql` file.. but how?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You could use something similar that's done by [mongeez](https://github.com/hzpz/mongeez-spring-boot-starter). This is basically a starter for spring-boot that runs scripts before spring-data-mongodb beans are initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You could tag along and leverage spring-boot's initialization lifecycle, where after wiring the beans, it executes all `CommandLineRunner` beans.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class YourApplication {
    final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Autowired
    private MongoRepository repo;

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner preLoadMongo() throws Exception {
        return args -> {
            //repo.doSOmethingInMongoDB
       }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(YourApplication.class, args);
    }
```